# Taking View Screenshot Crash - UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Only in ViewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, class-hierarchy, childviewcontroller

I am facing strange issue which is when I used following code to take screen shot in **viewWillAppear** app crashes

```
let renderr = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.view.bounds.size)
let image = renderr.image { (ctxt) in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
 }
```

Strange thing is in **viewDidLoad**  and **viewDidAppear** it is not crashing

Following is stack trace

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<App.FavPicVC: 0x7fcde2557bc0> should have parent view controller:(null) but actual parent is:<App.MyPicsVC: 0x7fcde26065b0>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111e5a29b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110e4c735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111e5a0f5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000117ca4749 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _associatedViewControllerForwardsAppearanceCallbacks:performHierarchyCheck:isRoot:] + 272
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000117ca4b4d -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 256
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000117cb63ce -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 456
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011753e27f _moveViewToTemporaryWindow + 496
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000011753dc58 _UIDrawViewRectAfterCommit + 173
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000117c99e88 -[UIView drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:] + 33
    9   App                 0x000000010fd59b1f $S19App8FavPicVCC14viewWillAppearyySbFySo30UIGraphicsImageRendererContextCXEfU_ + 655
    10  App                 0x000000010fd59bad $S19App8FavPicVCC14viewWillAppearyySbFySo30UIGraphicsImageRendererContextCXEfU_TA + 13
    11  App                 0x000000010fd59bbc $SSo30UIGraphicsImageRendererContextCIgg_ABIegg_TR + 12
    12  App                 0x000000010fd59c01 $SSo30UIGraphicsImageRendererContextCIgg_ABIegg_TRTA + 17
    13  App                 0x000000010fd59c48 $SSo30UIGraphicsImageRendererContextCIegg_ABIyBy_TR + 56
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001177b5155 -[UIGraphicsRenderer runDrawingActions:completionActions:format:error:] + 409
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001177b4f8e -[UIGraphicsRenderer runDrawingActions:completionActions:error:] + 104
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00000001177b33b5 -[UIGraphicsImageRenderer imageWithActions:] + 163
    17  App                 0x000000010fd59754 $S19App8FavPicVCC14viewWillAppearyySbF + 868
    18  App                 0x000000010fd59d23 $S19App8FavPicVCC14viewWillAppearyySbFTo + 51
    19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117cd86e3 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 690
    20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117cd8c49 __52-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]_block_invoke + 265
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111edc8b3 -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 163
    22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117cd89d7 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 1446
    23  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117cd8e74 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 131
    24  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117cda68d -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 696
    25  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117ca4cdc -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 655
    26  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117cb63ce -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 456
    27  App                 0x000000010fd9e617 $S19App10SideMenuVCC08addChildF033_B2AA86EDE92945C8C278D22E699991A7LLyySo16UIViewControllerCF + 1031
    28  App                 0x000000010fd9fa23 $S19App10SideMenuVCC10itemTapped0G05indexyAA0dE8ListItemV_SitF + 83
    29  App                 0x000000010fd9fa69 $S19App10SideMenuVCCAA0dE18ItemTappedDelegateA2aDP04itemH00J05indexyAA0de4ListG0V_SitFTW + 9
    30  App                 0x000000010fd9d104 $S19App14SideMenuListVCC9tableView_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableI0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 468
    31  App                 0x000000010fd9d80b $S19App14SideMenuListVCC9tableView_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableI0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 107
    32  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117af8d29 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1813
    33  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117af8f44 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 344
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00000001175af97e _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
    35  UIKitCore                           0x000000011759e424 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 384
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00000001175cd870 _afterCACommitHandler + 135
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111dbd037 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111db74ce __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111db7b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111db7221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    41  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011b4a31dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    42  UIKitCore                           0x00000001175a4115 UIApplicationMain + 140
    43  App                 0x000000010fdaac17 main + 71
    44  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001152ab551 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is view hierarchy

ViewController.Main.View -> ViewController.MyPickView.View -> ViewController.FavPic.View

What is scenario

From Side Menu  I tapped **My Pick Button** 
 -> Delegate this to ViewController.Main  
 -> in Main ViewController Add ViewController.MyPickView as child viewController 
->  ViewController.MyPickView has containerView which has ViewController.FavPic as childViewController

Note: Please don't mark it as duplicate I have seen many question with similar error but none of them help

Any Help would be appreciated

**EDIT CODE**

Step1 : Setup Main Controller with side menu. Full code available in my question in link  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209805/side-menu-handling-ios

Step2 : Now When user select **MyPic** option from side menu `addChildVC` Method is called

```
    private func addChildVC (_ vc:UIViewController) {
        self.removeAllChild()
        self.addChild(vc)
        vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)
        self.currentCenterViewController = vc

    }

    private func removeAllChild() {
        self.children.forEach{$0.willMove(toParent: nil);$0.view.removeFromSuperview();$0.removeFromParent()}
    }
```

**MYPic** View Controller has Container View with embed **FavPic**

Comment: May be the transition is not fully completed try execute it with some delay like 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: Did you try to perform this in `viewDidAppear` which may be anyway the better place for taking a screenshot?

Comment: @d4Rk in ViewDidAppear it is not crashing Any Reason behind ?

Comment: Basically, that's just the more elegant solution of what @SahilManchanda suggested ;-) I think it's because all the layouting, whatever is sure to be done here.

Comment: @d4Rk In that case why viewDiDLoad  case is working ?

Comment: Eh, ok... that's a good question... no idea really.. maybe viewWillAppear is just kind of in between some state?! At least according to your problem... no clue, really, just guessing now^^

Comment: @d4Rk I think because child view controller (My PIC VC)  has also child view controller  (FAV Pic) I am also guessing it. hope someone can answer it

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya if you could share some code of that viewcontroller. may be it helps in debugging.

Comment: @SahilManchanda Okay Let me find useful code to be asked